# Python Dict() sorting according to datetime

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, datetime

I have one file with so many values those are as below

```
{'Name':'xyz','Date':'Thu Jun 26 13:14:17 +0000 2008'}
{'Name':'xyz','Date':'Thu Jun 19 13:14:17 +0000 2009'}
{'Name':'xyz','Date':'Thu Jun 26 13:15:17 +0000 2008'}
```

How to sort these values according to date and time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file has these one per line, you'll need to convert to real `dict`s, e.g. with `json.loads` or `ast.literal_eval`, then sort:

```
import json
import datetime

def parse_date(datestr):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(datestr, '%a %b %m %H:%M:%S %z %Y')

with open(myfilename) as f:
    mydicts = map(json.loads, filter(str.strip, f))
    # This sorts on date value, but leaves them as original str
    # in dict, can convert ahead of time if you want, or not, as you please
    sorteddicts = sorted(mydicts, key=lambda d: parse_date(d['Date'])]
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'` you should use `datetime.datetime.strptime`

Comment: `ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%a %b %m %H:%M:%S %z %Y'`

Comment: Odd; [the docs seem to be pretty clear here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). Might need to install `pytz` to get support for timezone aware `datetime`s? Fixed the other issue, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dateutil.parser` for parsing dates and add the proper `key` in the `sort` function.

This works -

```
In [20]: from dateutil.parser import parse

In [21]: l = [{'Name':'xyz','Date':'Thu Jun 26 13:14:17 +0000 2008'},
{'Name':'xyz','Date':'Thu Jun 19 13:14:17 +0000 2009'},
{'Name':'xyz','Date':'Thu Jun 26 13:15:17 +0000 2008'}]

In [22]: sorted(l, key=lambda x: parse(x['Date']))
Out[22]:
[{'Date': 'Thu Jun 26 13:14:17 +0000 2008', 'Name': 'xyz'},
 {'Date': 'Thu Jun 26 13:15:17 +0000 2008', 'Name': 'xyz'},
 {'Date': 'Thu Jun 19 13:14:17 +0000 2009', 'Name': 'xyz'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `email` package from stdlib, to parse the date format into "seconds since the Epoch":

```
>>> from email.utils import parsedate_tz, mktime_tz
>>> mktime_tz(parsedate_tz('Thu Jun 26 13:14:17 +0000 2008'))
1214486057
```

It is easy to sort `dict`s by `Date` field:

```
>>> sorted(dicts, key=lambda d: mktime_tz(parsedate_tz(d['Date'])))
[{'Date': 'Thu Jun 26 13:14:17 +0000 2008', 'Name': 'xyz'},
 {'Date': 'Thu Jun 26 13:15:17 +0000 2008', 'Name': 'xyz'},
 {'Date': 'Thu Jun 19 13:14:17 +0000 2009', 'Name': 'xyz'}]
```

To load json objects from the file, you could use [code from @ShadowRanger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35099083/4279).